# How to use a dynamic interval in Laravel Carbon in order to only select a date 10 days in the future from mysql

Tags: laravel, date, intervals

I need to get db results where the question answered_at (date) is itself plus some days, from a column. I've tried a lot using Carbon and also mysql INTERVAL but I get stuck on the syntax.

I'm using Laravel 6 and Carbon.

I have a table called "questions" and from there I would like to get the id of a question that was answered_at a certain date plus an amount of days that I have in another column called "repeat".

Something like this:

```
->where( 'answered_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays('repeat'))
```

However, I can't just write "repeat", as it doesn't recognize it as a table. If I write a number in there it actually works.

This works:

```
->where( 'answered_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays(10))
```

But since the dynamic amount of days to add to a date comes from the database, I must have it as a dynamic field. I have tried to get it before the query, and use it as a $variable, however - that creates two different mysql-queries and would mean bad performance.

So I would like this to work, however I can't figure out the syntax:

```
->where( 'answered_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays('COLUMN_REPEAT_FROM_DB'))
```

I have also tried this:

```
->whereRaw("DATE_ADD(answered_at, INTERVAL 10 DAY) <= NOW()")
```

which works but INTERVAL 10 DAY is then hard coded and

```
->whereRaw("DATE_ADD(answered_at, INTERVAL 'repeat' DAY) <= NOW()")
```

doesn't work either..syntax!

The entire query looks like this:

```
$question = \DB::table('questions')
     ->where( 'answered_at', '<', Carbon::now()->subDays('repeat'))
     ->value('answered_at');
```

(I'm getting answered_at as value just to see which date comes out in order to test it, will change to id later and pass on to another function).

Any pointers highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the right way with your last query, but you used wrong quotes.

You should use backquotes instead, in order to specify column name:

```php
$query->whereRaw("DATE_ADD(answered_at, INTERVAL `repeat` DAY) <= NOW()")
```

Alternatively, you can use this query with the same result:

```php
$query->whereRaw("DATEDIFF(NOW(), answered_at) >= `repeat`")
```

Though, the calculcation itself seems wrong. If you want to select rows which have current date *within* `answered_at + repeat DAYS` interval then it should be `>=` in your query and `<=` in mine.

Comment: @Rbbn Glad to help :) Carbon is useless here, because all needed data in the DB already.